Get username from a Clerk user Next.js and Clerk 5
I’m building a blog and I want to display the author’s username at the end of each blog post, but I don’t know how to retrieve it other than using the useUser() hook or currentUser(). The problem with these two solutions is that they display the current user’s username.
next.js 14, clerk v5
